# Best Practice for Managing Large Application Configuration

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Say I am building a large service `MyService`, which contains a variety of `SubServices` that may perform operations in a multithreaded context. Designed in C++ like so:

```
class MyService : public MyServiceInterface{
public:
    // Some public methods.
private:
    // Some private methods.

    // Some sub services. Assume that these are dependency injected.
    std::shared_ptr<SubServiceA> a;
    std::shared_ptr<SubServiceB> b;
    std::shared_ptr<SubServiceC> c;
```

`MyService` is configurable through a user-defined file which we parse into a data structure `MyServiceConfig`. This configuration is not read-only, the application may edit it during the course of operation. Assume that we have all of the concurrency primitives in place to manage any accesses.

My question is this- if all of my `SubServices` require not-necessarily exclusive parts of this configuration, is it good practice to pass a `std::shared_ptr<MyServiceConfig>` to any `SubService`? It seems strange to me to expose the entire configuration to every system, if it is not required. There are several solutions to this (passing individual pieces if the subset of required configuration is small, maintaining internal structures in `MyServiceConfig` that perform logical division for known `SubServices`), but I'm failing to see clearly what would be best. Is there an established best-practice pattern for configuring large-scale services and their sub-services?

Comment: `This configuration is not read-only, the application may edit it during the course of operation` why is that? IMHO each subservice should have its own configuration, and a mapping between `MyServiceConfig` to -> `{SubserviceConfig_i}0<i<n` should be made.

Comment: I agree that ideally that the term 'configuration' implies that it is an object that should be `const` after initialization, but I'm working in an existing system in which this is not the case. How would you implement this mapping?

Comment: what is the expected behavior when `MyServiceConfig` changes?

Comment: All `SubServices` will see an updated version of the config.